# Is there a way to see details for groups in a query?

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008

I need to make a report in SSRS that will output data in this format:

```
Person    | DocumentID | Data1 | Data2 | .....
----------------------------------------------
Mr. Smith |            |       |       | 
          | #123021312 |    01 |    04 | .....
          | #132145681 |    07 |    00 | .....
Mr. Black |            |       |       | 
          | #912205112 |    11 |    08 | .....
          | #131135810 |    03 |    05 | .....
..............................................
```

So, there is a kind of a hierarchy to the query. There are detail records (data about documents) and group records (persons). If I would do just GROUP BY, I would be able to only see group records, and display some aggregate information, like, Max of Data1, or Count of Document ID. Instead, I want to be able to see both aggregate and detail rows.

I tried googling and couldn't find any information about wether this is possible in T-SQL (or SSRS, for that matter). Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible....

**Flat Data**

```
Declare @T TABLE (Person VARCHAR(25),  DocumentID VARCHAR(25), Data1 VARCHAR(25), Data2 VARCHAR(25))

INSERT INTO @T (Person,DocumentID,Data1,Data2) VALUES
('Mr. Smith','#12345678A','01','04'),
('Mr. Smith','#98765432A','02','05'),
('Mr. Black','#12345678B','03','06'),
('Mr. Black','#98765432B','04','07')

SELECT  *
FROM    @T
```

**Tablix Setup Steps**

1. On your tablix that contains each of the fields in SSRS highlight the data row.
2. Right Click on the now visible row header with the 3 lines.
3. Select Add Group > Parent Group
4. In the group by drop down select Person then OK
5. The report will now be grouped by the Person column.

Bonus if you don't want the Person column showing to the right of the grouping simply delete the column.

[image: Finished Product]